# How to create a Python script that opens iterpreter's shell

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know how to ask this to Google, but I want to write a Python script that when executed, it will simply import some modules, and expose the ordinary Python interpreter shell so that the user can type commands and use the imported modules.

What is the least hackish way to accomplish this, preferably having to write a single file?

Comment: Are you on Linux/OS X/Unix?

Comment: Yes, Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Unix system, you can simply tell your script to open the interactive Python interpreter when it's done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -i

import re
```

For a Python-only solution, you can use the `code` module, passing it the invoker's environment so that definitions are inherited. If you don't mind also inheriting the `code` module itself, it can be as simple as this:

```
import code
import re  # etc.

code.interact(local=globals())
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> import code
>>> import re
>>> code.interact(local=globals())
Python 3.4.4 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:48:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'code', 're']
>>>
```